# How to calculate division between row and sum of this row's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am learning T-SQL with a microsoft sample DB, AdventureWorksLT2012. I am trying to get the percentage of the sales of each product. At this moment I have a query like this:

```
USE AdventureWorksLT2012;
GO

SELECT ProductTable.Name, TotalOrderItemsTable.TotalOrderedItems
FROM SalesLT.Product ProductTable INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ProductID, COUNT(*) As TotalOrderedItems
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail TotalOrderTable
GROUP BY ProductID) TotalOrderItemsTable ON ProductTable.ProductID = TotalOrderItemsTable.ProductID
```

Output so far:

```
Name                     TotalOrderedItems
AWC Logo Cap            |9
Bike Wash - Dissolver   |7
Chain                   |4
Classic Vest, M         |6
Classic Vest, S         |10
Front Brakes            |7
```

Desired output:

```
Name                     PercentageSale
AWC Logo Cap            |20.9...
Bike Wash - Dissolver   |16.2...
Chain                   |9.3...
Classic Vest, M         |14.0...
Classic Vest, S         |23.2...
Front Brakes            |16.2..
```

**I am trying to build a query like TotalOrderedItems/SUM(TotalOrderedItems) * 100**

```
SELECT ProductTable.Name, TotalOrderItemsTable.TotalOrderedItems / SUM(TotalOrderedItems) * 100
```

But I guess SUM(TotalOrderedItems) is not calculated yet, and thus is giving me errors.

Any ideas how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, 
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(COUNT(*))) OVER () as pct
FROM SalesLT.Product p JOIN
     SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail s
     ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.Name;
```

The subquery is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the percentage using window function `SUM`. `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER()` would give the total ordered items for all products.

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, 100.0*COUNT(*)/SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() as pct
FROM SalesLT.Product p
INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail s ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.Name
```

The existing query can also be extended.

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, 100.0*s.TotalOrderedItems/sum(s.TotalOrderedItems) as pct
FROM SalesLT.Product p
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProductID, COUNT(*) As TotalOrderedItems
            FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail TotalOrderTable
            GROUP BY ProductID) s ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.Name
```

Comment: I don't like the idea to group by name. Imagine 2 items have the same name but distincts PK, in this case productId? Different pricing. That would cause troubles.

Comment: in that case you'll have to `group by` id and name. check the edit.

Comment: @ZLK .. it is perfectly valid and works with window functions. you can try running it and verify.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option is using the window functions

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,PercentageScale = (TotalOrderedItems * 100.0)/sum(TotalOrderedItems) over () 
from  YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Name                    TotalOrderedItems   PercentageScale
AWC Logo Cap            9                   20.930232558139
Bike Wash - Dissolver   7                   16.279069767441
Chain                   4                   9.302325581395
Classic Vest, M         6                   13.953488372093
Classic Vest, S         10                  23.255813953488
Front Brakes            7                   16.279069767441
```